# In sql, is there a function to convert hexadecimal in GBK?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, gbk

I have this .php script to receive username and password from another page:

```
$req2 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="'.$_POST['val1'].'"and password="'.$_POST['val2'].'"');

$req2 -> execute();
```

My database accepts GBK language, but when i enter a valid GBK symbol in hexadecimal(0xbf5c which a chinese symbol) the query does not work (but it works with the chinese symbol directly).

So, is there a function in sql to transform hexadecimals in GBK symbol ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this PDo you are using? If so your are doing it wrong, you should use placeholders and then execute( array($var1,$var2, ..)) your prepared statement. Maybe its the gbk escaping issue you are having.

Comment: yes pdo, no just consider to be on the "user" side.

Comment: Did u try doing what i suggested?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually i don't understand it. What is the use of placeholders in this case ?

Comment: Its to escape values, and avoid sql injections, i am thinking maybe your gbk characters are conflicting with the query somehow.

Comment: I hope you're not using this in production. If someone `POST`s `val1='; DROP TABLE users; --`, your DB is gone. Alternatively, whatever action is executed, would be applied to **all** the users in the DB if someone `POST`ed `val1=1=1'; --`